# Line-break and paginate an input string for a printer

Tags: java, string, printing

Here is the problem statement:

> Restructure a String for a printer. The printer can only print 40 lines across the page and a page can only hold 20 lines. The bottom of the page should contain "Page X" where X is the page number. Page numbers start at 1.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.lang.String;

public class Problem11
{
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of <code>Problem11</code>.
     */
    public Problem11()
    {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String phrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog who bit him on the butt.";
        //String phrase = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
        int max_lines = 20;
        int max_characters = 40;
        int page_num = 0;
        int carriage_ret = 0;
        int start_position = 10;
        int end_position = 0;
        String printline = "";

        do
        {
            start_position = carriage_ret;
            end_position = start_position + max_characters;
            carriage_ret = findSpace(phrase, start_position, end_position) + start_position;

            System.out.println("You are on line 37.");

            if ( carriage_ret > phrase.length())
            {
                carriage_ret = phrase.length();
                break;
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    carriage_ret = findSpace(phrase, start_position, end_position) + start_position;
            //}

            printline = phrase.substring(start_position, carriage_ret);
            System.out.println(printline);

            System.out.println(carriage_ret + "");

            if ( start_position > phrase.length())
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);

    }

    private static int findSpace( String phrase, int start, int end )
    {
        String tempString = " ";
        int result = 0;

        if ( end > phrase.length())
        {
            end = phrase.length();
          }

          tempString = phrase.substring(start,end);

          result = tempString.lastIndexOf(" ");
          System.out.println(tempString);

          return result;
    }
}
```

It compiles, but I don't get the results asked for.
I get an infinite loop with the whole phrase not broken up at the 40th character.

Comment: Please document the problem with your results.

Comment: What  I get is an infinite loop with the whole phrase not broken up at the 40th character.

Comment: Also the split has to be on whitespace.

Comment: I've edited in your comment, usually you should usually [edit] the question to include additional information rather than rely on comments. I also, added the [tag:java] tag as that appears to the the relevant programming language. For questions that include code like this you should always add the tag for the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you have an infinite loop is this line of code:

```
        } while (true);
```

The reason that you're not getting a carriage return after 40 characters appears to be that you're executing:

```
System.out.println(tempString);
```

inside of your `findSpace` method and it's not taking into account the position that was calculated as the last whitespace before the 40 character limit.